# (SQL-T-SQL) Select Command to Have only certain values?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqltransaction

Here is my table **app_extra**:

AppID;AppExtraID
100;0
100;1
100;3
100;7
100;8
100;9
110;0
110;2
110;4
110;7
110;9
115;0
115;2
115;6
115;8
120;0
120;1
120;10
130;0
130;7
130;8
130;10
140;0
140;1
140;3
150;0
150;2
150;6
150;7
150;8
150;10
160;0
160;8
160;10
165;0
165;8
165;10
170;0
170;2
170;8
170;10
180;0
180;1
180;5
180;7
180;10
185;0
185;1
185;7
185;10
190;0
190;2

I would like to know how to have only the AppID **that doesn't have 9 and 10 AppExtraID**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are getting at...

```
SELECT DISTINCT AppID
FROM app_extra 
WHERE AppID NOT IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT AppID from app_Extra 
   WHERE AppExtraID IN (9, 10))
```

The inner select will identify all App ID's which have a 9 or a 10 extra.  These rows will then be excluded in the main select.  Any AppID which is related to 9 or 10 will be eliminated, even if they also have another extra ID.

Comment: That wil get records that only are missing either 9 or 10 not those that are missing both.

Comment: That should get all records which have neither a 9 or a 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct AppId
from app_extra
where AppExtraID not in (9, 10)
```

Modified to suit your comment's desire.

Comment: Beat me to it. Great examples.

Comment: No, this will only removes the rows that contains 9 or 10. I want the T-SQL command to have only the ID's that DOESN'T have 9 or 10.

Comment: @MartinGemme I have modified my answer.  This will give you what you need.

Comment: @Martin - You asked for a query that returns all rows where the AppExtraID is NOT a 9 or 10. That's what they gave you. Please clarify your request if this is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

To get a unique list of `AppID` that fulfill the reqirement:

```
SELECT AppID 
FROM   tbl
WHERE  AppExtraID NOT IN (9, 10)
GROUP  BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT AppID FROM app_extra WHERE AppExtraID NOT IN(9,10)
```

Comment: No, this will only removes the rows that contains 9 or 10. I want the T-SQL command to have only the ID's that DOESN'T have 9 or 10.